# How can I use buttons to add items to a cart at the bottom of my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page I made that just has a simple grid with pizza and toppings, and each item on the grid has an add to cart button underneath it. Below the grid is a cart, which is essentially just three columns: Item, price, and quantity. I am not quite sure how to make the add to cart buttons work properly, and at least make them add the right items in the right format (Item under item, price under price, etc, rather then all of that info smushed under the item column.)

My knowledge of JavaScript is really not much at all so I've just kind of been doing some trial and error here. Right now I have the first button set to create a paragraph element with what would be the item name, and append it under the item section.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>  Pizza Planet  </h1>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Select your items:</h2>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="item" id="pizza"> Pizza <img src="https://cdn.modpizza.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/mod-pizza-maddy-default-e1479167621575.png" /><button class="addToCartButton" type="button" onclick="addItemToCart()">Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Pepperoni <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/5c0798c72c6641059597e35e.png" /><button type>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Mushrooms <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/585ea634cb11b227491c352c.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Onions <img src="http://www.pngnames.com/files/3/Onion-Transparent-File.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Meatballs <img src="http://doughocracy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Meatballs-1-e1437181629229.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Peppers <img src="https://www.actaturcica.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Bell-Pepper-PNG-Image.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Olives <img src="http://www.pngnames.com/files/3/Olives-Transparent-Background.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Bacon <img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-baconfood-meat-fried-pork-cooked-941524618065kjlnp.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Prosciutto <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/250323_thumb.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
                <div class="item"> Ham <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ham-PNG.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
            </div> 
            <div class="cart">
                    <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
                    <div class="cart-row">
                        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-items" id="itemsList">

                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-total" id="cartTotal">
                        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                        <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
.cart {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
}

.cart-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
}

.cart-column {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.cart-row {
    display: flex;
}

.cart-item {
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.cart-items {
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.cart-price {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: white;
}

.cart-quantity {
    width: 35%;
}

.cart-item-title {
    color: #333;
    margin-left: .5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.cart-item-image {
    width: 75px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.cart-row:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.cart-row:last-child .cart-column {
    border: none;
}

.cart-total {
    text-align: end;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.cart-total-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.cart-total-price {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

And the simple JavaScript code:

```
function addItemToCart() {
    var itemInCart = document.createElement("P")
    itemInCart.innerHTML = "Pizza";
    document.getElementById("itemsList").appendChild(itemInCart);
}
```

When I click add to cart under pizza, it adds the word pizza to the cart section of the page, under the item column. So it works as far as that goes. But I don't believe I am doing this in the best way. How can I add the price and quantity as well? I am open to any suggestions, even if it means completely overhauling the shopping cart for something better.

Comment: You'll need ***quite a bit*** to make this a fully functional **application** instead of just an **updating web page**.  Right now, you aren't tracking the items being added to the cart, or even what is selected, so even though the page updates, you have no way to do anything with that later.  Before taking on a task like this, I would suggest spending some time getting your JavaScript skills up a bit, because this kind of app will require it.  You might also take a look at one of the many SPA frameworks out there to take advantage of to not reinvent the wheel too much.

Comment: @Claies Yeah, I figured it wouldn't be an easy thing to do. This is for a project I had kind of dumped on me last second, which sucks when I've really got no prior experience using JavaScript. Oh well. It's a learning experience, so it's not a total loss. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction, I'll make note of the SPA framework. Thank you!

Comment: Something like Angular or React or Vue.js, any one of these 3 are designed with the idea of turning a collection of individual web pages into a Single Page Application (SPA).  They use JavaScript to programmatically generate web pages based on inputs and calculations, rather than using JavaScript to modify HTML content.

Comment: For a project this size, I'd recommend Vue. It allows for very fast prototyping and can handle both very small gadgets as well as large scale SPA's. The reason I recommend it over Angular or React is that it's a bit friendlier and it somehow pushes you to learn JavaScript the *right* way, without falling into its pitfalls. But I'm not saying your journey will be easy, by any means.

Comment: But to stick to your question: you'll need a virtual space (typically called `vm` = virtual model) in which you define the logic of your application, including data (which drives what your page renders) and methods bound to elements (which allow interaction with your data). This will help you display products, add them to a cart and, eventually, send the cart's contents to a server where an action will be triggered - adding it to a database and/or sending an email. This would take a seasoned dev a few days, provided he has the design.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are suggesting frameworks and libraries like Vue, React and Angular, whilst these are excellent tools, they have quite a steep learning curve especially if you are not familiar with JS, for this reason I would suggest not using them for now.

First up, I would advise using [jQuery](http://https:/https://jquery.com/), this little javascript library will make things like this worlds easier to implement and save you writing a bunch less code you will also be able to learn what "vanilla JS" functions you are replacing with the jQuery alternative. For example

```
var itemInCart = document.createElement("P")
itemInCart.innerHTML = "Pizza";
document.getElementById("itemsList").appendChild(itemInCart);
```

becomes

```
$('#itemList').append("<p> Pizza </p>");
```

To include jQuery, put the following in your head tag

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
```

The first thing I would do, is assign an ID to each of these toppings and and a  attribute of how much it costs, and an ID on the button. On click of these buttons lets populate an object, called *pizza*.

So the updated HTML would look like this

```
          <div id="content">
          <h2>Select your items:</h2>
          <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="item" id="pizza" data-cost="10"> Pizza <img src="https://cdn.modpizza.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/mod-pizza-maddy-default-e1479167621575.png" /><button id="pizza-btn" class="addToCartButton" type="button">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="pepperoni" data-cost="2"> Pepperoni <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/5c0798c72c6641059597e35e.png" /><button id="topping-pepperoni-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="mushrooms" data-cost="1"> Mushrooms <img src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/585ea634cb11b227491c352c.png" /><button id="topping-mushrooms-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="onions" data-cost="1"> Onions <img src="http://www.pngnames.com/files/3/Onion-Transparent-File.png" /><button id="topping-onions-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="meatballs" data-cost="2"> Meatballs <img src="http://doughocracy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Meatballs-1-e1437181629229.png" /><button  id="topping-meatballs-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="peppers" data-cost="1"> Peppers <img src="https://www.actaturcica.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Bell-Pepper-PNG-Image.png" /><button  id="topping-peppers-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="olives" data-cost="1"> Olives <img src="http://www.pngnames.com/files/3/Olives-Transparent-Background.png" /><button  id="topping-olives-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="bacon" data-cost="2"> Bacon <img src="https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-baconfood-meat-fried-pork-cooked-941524618065kjlnp.png" /><button>Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="prosciutto" data-cost="3"> Prosciutto <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/250323_thumb.png" /><button id="topping-prosciutto-btn">Order</button></div>
              <div class="item" id="ham" data-cost="2"> Ham <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ham-PNG.png" /><button id="topping-ham-btn">Order</button></div>
          </div>
          <div class="cart">
                  <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>

                  <table id="cart-table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ITEM</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>

                  <div class="cart-total" id="cartTotal">
                      <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                      <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I would then update the item, cost and table on click of the button to update the pizza variable. Here is a short script I have prepared.

```
$().ready(function(){
  // our pizza variable
  let pizza = {
    cost : 0.00,
    toppings: []
  };

  let pizzaFlag = 0;

  // getting the table and assigning it to a variable, making it a jQuery object
  let cartTable = $('#cart-table');
  // getting the total price label and making it a jQuery object.
  let totalLabel = $('.cart-total-price');

  //adding toppings to pizza
  $('[id^=topping-]').click(function(){
    if(pizzaFlag == 0){
      alert("Please add a pizza first");
    }else{
      // splitting out the id as a name
      let topping = this.id.split('-')[1];
      // adding the topping name to the pizza topping array
      pizza.toppings.push(topping);
      // adding the topping cost to the pizza cost, then changing the total text to reflect the new price
      pizza.cost += $('#'+topping).data().cost;
      totalLabel.text('$' + pizza.cost);
      // creating a table row with the topping name and cost, appending to the table
      cartTable.append(
        "<tr>" +
          "<td> "+ topping +" </td> " +
          "<td> "+ $('#'+topping).data().cost +" </td> " +
          "<td> 1 </td> " +
        "<tr>"
      );
    }
    // logging out the pizza to the console
    console.log(pizza);
  });

  // adding a pizza
  $('#pizza-btn').click(function(){
    if(pizzaFlag == 1){
      alert('You may only have one pizza at the moment');
    }else{
      pizzaFlag = 1;
      pizza.cost += 10;
      console.log(pizza);
      cartTable.append(
        "<tr>" +
          "<td> Pizza </td> " +
          "<td> 10 </td> " +
          "<td> 1 </td> " +
        "<tr>"
      );
      totalLabel.text('$10');
    }

  });



});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to get the data to be stored in variables and attributes rather than just having a useless updating web page... For my project, I will need to add some sort of checkout after this, and if JQuery is my route to an actual working project then that is amazing. Thank you so much. Do you have any suggestions on where I can get a grip on the basics of JQuery? I'm not sure how much I'll need to know for this project, but I need all I can get ASAP. I have experience with C++ so I'm not completely knew to programming FWIW.

Comment: Honestly jQuery is one of those things where you learn it at the rate of a need to know basis.

If you want to know how to change the color of something you would google "change text of h1 with jquery" and you will find someone posting about using the .css() method.

Comment: An important thing to get you started though is that you must wrap event listeners in a $().ready(function(){});

Additionally, to select something with by id you would use $('#yourID');
but to select via class you would use $('.yourClass'); The same way you use CSS

Comment: No worries, if you need any other help hit me on instagram - i check there more often @anthonycarnell

Answer (score 1):

When I said Vue allows for fast prototyping, I meant it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#pizzaShop',
  data: {
    toppings: [{
      name: 'Pepperoni',
      img: 'https://images.freshop.com/129984/d66adc5d9217bed0f60b8690535a6895_medium.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Mushrooms',
      img: 'https://freepngimage.com/content/uploads/images/t_mushrooms-1775.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Onions',
      img: 'https://www.seekpng.com/png/small/363-3630064_onion-transparent-file-onion.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Meatballs',
      img: 'https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.w8H3lGeWK-y3aTrrcauC9QHaHP',
    }, {
      name: 'Peppers',
      img: 'https://www.actaturcica.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Bell-Pepper-PNG-Image.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Olives',
      img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPoqKIMKjhz8trmtKJAUdMDRJKhOHJoDscP2uhef8OFMdSmzJq',
    }, {
      name: 'Bacon',
      img: 'https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-baconfood-meat-fried-pork-cooked-941524618065kjlnp.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Prosciutto',
      img: 'https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/250323_thumb.png',
    }, {
      name: 'Ham',
      img: 'https://pm1.narvii.com/6726/2a17f7f63b817ecbf2772076822e8353d7d724f2v2_00.jpg',
    }],
    cart: [],
    selection: [],
    showSelection: false,
  },
  computed: {
    currentPizza() {
      return this.currency.format(this.currentPizzaPrice);
    },
    currentPizzaPrice() {
      return Math.max(this.selection.length - 2, 0) * 0.5 + 3;
    },
    currency() {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IE', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'EUR',
      });
    },
    cartTotal() {
      return this.currency.format(
        this.cart.map(i => i.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      )
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isSelected(topping) {
      return this.selection.indexOf(topping) > -1;
    },
    toggle(topping) {
      if (this.isSelected(topping)) {
        this.selection.splice(this.selection.indexOf(topping), 1);
      } else {
        this.selection.push(topping)
      }
    },
    prettyfy(obj) {
      return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
    },
    addToCart() {
      this.cart.push({
        toppings: this.toppings.filter(t => this.isSelected(t)).map(t => t.name),
        price: this.currentPizzaPrice
      });
      this.selection = [];
    },
    pizzaName(pizza) {
      return pizza.toppings.length ?
        `Pizza ${pizza.toppings.join(', ')}` :
        'Plain pizza';
    },
    deletePizza(pizza) {
      const index = this.cart.indexOf(pizza);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.cart.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.toppings {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.toppings>* {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 170px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.toppings>* .btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.toppings>*:hover {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.toppings>* img {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.col-sm-12>img {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cart-contents li span:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cart-contents li span:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cart-contents li code:last-child {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="pizzaShop">
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <h1 class="text-center my-5">Make your own pizza</h1>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
      <b-col lg="4" md="4" sm="12">
        <img src="https://cdn.modpizza.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/mod-pizza-maddy-default-e1479167621575.png" />
        <b-row>
          <b-col>
            <ol class="cart-contents mt-3">
              <li v-for="pizza in cart">
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <span v-text="pizzaName(pizza)"></span>
                  <span v-text="currency.format(pizza.price)" class="mx-2"></span>
                  <code v-html="`&times;`" @click.prevent="deletePizza(pizza)"></code>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ol>
            <h4 class="text-center">Cart total: {{cartTotal}}</h4>
            <code class="text-center d-block">[2 ingredients included for each pizza]</code>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="item in selection">{{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-col>
      <b-col lg="6" md="8" sm="12" class="offset-lg-1">
        <b-row class="toppings">
          <b-col v-for="topping in toppings" sm="4" col class="py-3" @click="toggle(topping)">
            <img :src="topping.img" />
            <h5>{{ topping.name }}</h5>
            <b-btn :variant="isSelected(topping) ? 'outline-secondary': 'danger'" size="sm" v-text="isSelected(topping) ? 'Remove' : 'Add'" class="border-transparent"></b-btn>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <b-row>
          <b-col sm="8" md="6" lg="6" class="offset-lg-3 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
            <b-btn variant="info" class="btn-block my-5" @click.prevent="addToCart()">Add to cart ({{currentPizza}})</b-btn>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row class="mb-5">
      <b-col>
        <pre>// selection: 
{{prettyfy(selection)}}</pre>
        <pre>// cart: 
{{prettyfy(cart)}}</pre>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

Some of your images are blocked on stack, so I used others.
I've written this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/Lx5dr3es/) (for the SCSS support).

Comment: Dude this is awesome. If you can do that with Vue that quickly, I've got to check it out. I appreciate the suggestion and all your help so much.